# Top navigation bar design with PrimeNG

Tags: primeng, angular-ng

With bootstrap, I was able to design a navigation bar easily. For example https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/#navbars

However, in PrimeNG I can't find a component or a panel to create a navigation bar with logo, menu options and hamburger icon.

Any idea?

Comment: Also had that problem, look in the PrimeNG documentation - https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/menubar.

Comment: ok thanks! I took a look at this component but I couldn't see an option to add a logo at the begining of the menubar. Maybe it's possible.

Comment: You may look into this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46627436/how-to-add-app-logo-image-to-primeng-menubar